# Error on server Local host working fine

Tags: php, codeigniter

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/opt/php54/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_curl.dll'
>   - /opt/php54/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_curl.dll:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: Unknown
>
> Line Number: 0
>
> Backtrace:

Comment: which server are you using godady?

Answer (score 0):

It means there is an extension or zend_extension line in one of your php configuration file (php.ini, or another close to it) that is trying to load that extension : ixed.5.2.lin

But the corresponding file doesn't exist.

Try to search in the .ini files that are loaded by PHP (phpinfo() can indicate which ones are) : one of them should try to load that extension.
Just comment the correspond line.

Answer (score -1):

In the php.ini (/etc/php.ini in my case) I commented out the line extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll and restarted Apache which solved my problem.